# Vulkan ShaderViewportIndexLayerEXT support

Tags: vulkan, spir-v

I'm in the process of porting some rendering code to Vulkan. I've been using the SPIR-V cross-compiler to avoid the requirement of re-writing all my shaders, which has been working well in most cases, but now I've hit an issue I just can't get past.

I have a vertex shader being compiled to SPIR-V that uses `SV_RenderTargetArrayIndex`. This maps to `ShaderViewportIndexLayerEXT` in SPIRV. The device I'm running on (an NVidia 3090 with latest drivers) supports the `VK_EXT_shader_viewport_index_layer` extension (which is core in 1.2), and I'm explicitly enabling both `shaderOutputViewportIndex` and `shaderOutputLayer` in the `VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Features` struct (chained off the `vkPhysicalDeviceFeatures2` which is in turn chained on `pNext` for the `vkDeviceCreateInfo` struct.

I've also added the line:

`[[vk::ext_extension("SPV_EXT_shader_viewport_index_layer")]]`

To the .hlsl source file, and verified the SPIRV being output contains the extension reference.

The validation layer is whining, with:

`Validation Error: [ VUID-VkShaderModuleCreateInfo-pCode-01091 ] Object 0: handle = 0x1e66c477eb0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xa7bb8db6 | vkCreateShaderModule(): The SPIR-V Capability (ShaderViewportIndexLayerEXT) was declared, but none of the requirements were met to use it. The Vulkan spec states: If pCode declares any of the capabilities listed in the SPIR-V Environment appendix, one of the corresponding requirements must be satisfied`

Is there something else I need to do to enable this feature on the device? Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated.

(I can always drop the requirement to use this feature - realistically in my use case on DX12 it's not gaining me much if anything, but I'd rather figure this out!)

Comment: When that extension was promoted to Vulkan 1.2, the ShaderViewportIndexLayerEXT SPIR-V capability was replaced by the ShaderViewportIndex and ShaderLayer capabilities. Perhaps your SPIR-V shader is using the old capability and this is the problem? You can check by disassembling it with `spirv-dis` and looking at the `OpCapability` lines.

Comment: Yup, it's using the old capability (I see 

`Capability(ShaderViewportIndexLayerEXT);`

in the disassembly, along with the line:

`Extension("SPV_EXT_shader_viewport_index_layer");`

What's the syntax to push it to use `ShaderViewportIndex` and `ShaderLayer`?

Comment: I unfortunately don't know anything about HLSL. What are you compiling it to SPIR-V with? If it's glslang, you might need to pass the `--target-env vulkan1.2` flag. If it's DXC, I'm not sure what to do but there might be a clue in the documentation somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using DXC, and specifying 1.2 as the target environment. With or without the `[[vk::ext_extension("SPV_EXT_shader_viewport_index_layer")]]` line I'm still seeing that extension enabled, so it's possible it's an issue with the dxc compiler just not supporting this functionality outside of the previous extension. Ignoring the warnings, the shaders function as expected, so it at least works, it just triggers a validation warning.